# How To Link To A SQL Server Table With An AD Group - Not An Individual User

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, dao

I am using access VBA and DAO to programmatically create linked tables.

I build a string like this:

```
strConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;Database=mydatabase;Server=myserver;
```

I then create the TableDef:

```
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stlocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, strConnect)
```

I then append the TableDef:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
```

**I want the tables created / linked under an AD Group instead of my user.**

I have tried numerous options and all I ever see when I create the table is:

```
...;UID=myuser;Trusted_Connection=Yes;..
```

Is it possible to link a table using an AD Group instead of an Individual user?

P.S.  The AD group has datareader and datawriter rights to the database.

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't be using the ancient `SQL Server` ODBC driver. Use the current driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

It is the other way around. With a trusted connection, SQL reads the current logged on user and then looks up which rights might be granted to this user or the groups this user is a member of, and from this determines the final rights granted to the user. So try leaving out any SQL Server credentials, simply:

```
...;Trusted_Connection=Yes;..
```